# Perfect numbers, arrays, verification and operation

Tags: c, arrays, loops, perfect-numbers

I'm trying to write a code in C which would allow a maximum input of 10 elements (natural numbers) in an array, identify all perfect numbers in the array, and do the product of all non-perfect numbers.

> Euclid proved that 2^{p−1}(2^p−1) is an even perfect number whenever 2^p−1
>   is prime (Euclid, Prop. IX.36). For example, the first four perfect
>   numbers are generated by the formula 2^{p−1}(2^p−1), with p a prime
>   number, as follows: for p = 2:   2^1(2^2−1) = 6 for p = 3:   2^2(2^3−1) =
>   28 for p = 5:   2^4(2^5−1) = 496 for p = 7:   2^6(2^7−1) = 8128.
>   (source: wikipedia)

When I compile the program, I get a triplicate or higher repetition of declaration of the perfect number.

e.g.:

> ... t[10] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6}
>
> '6' is a perfect number.
>   '6' is a perfect number.
>   '6' is a perfect number.
>   ...

I also get a weird products.

e.g.:

> ... t[10] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 28}
>
> '28' is a perfect number.
>   '28' is a perfect number.
>   '28' is a perfect number.
>   '28' is a perfect number.
>   '28' is a perfect number.
>   '28' is a perfect number.
>   '28' is a perfect number.
>   '28' is a perfect number.
>   '28' is a perfect number.
>   '28' is a perfect number.
>   '28' is a perfect number.
>   '28' is a perfect number.
>   '28' is a perfect number.
>   ...
>   The product of the non-perfect numbers is -1677721600

I'm really new to c, I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong, but I wouldn't an handout either. Some guidance would be much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_BOUND 9  /*Array's bound*/

main() {

int i, /*array index*/
    t[i],
    d, /*divider*/ 
    sum, /*result for perfect number validation*/
    product; /*product of all non-perfect number in array*/

i = 0;

printf("Enter your natural numbers. \n");

for (i = 0; i <= MAX_BOUND; i++) {
printf("Number %d : ", i + 1);
scanf( "%d", &t[i]);
}

i = 0;
product = 1;
for (i = 0; i <= MAX_BOUND; i++) {   
    d = 1;
    sum = 0;
    while(d < t[i]) {
        if(t[i]%d == 0)
        sum = sum + d;
        d++;

            if(sum == t[i])
            printf("%d is a perfect number. \n", t[i]);
            else
            product = product * t[i];
    }
}  
printf("The product of the non-perfect numbers is %d \n", product);
getch();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your declaration of the array, you have undefined behaviour because you used the wrong size:

```
main() {

    int i, 
        t[i],
        d, /*divider*/ 
        sum, 
        product;

    i = 0;

    printf("Enter your natural numbers. \n");

    while (i <= 9) {
        printf("Number %d : ", i + 1);
        scanf( "%d", &t[i]);
        i++;
    }
```

You probably meant to declare

```
t[MAX_BOUND+1];
```

(`MAX_BOUND` would be wrong, since you use the element `t[MAX_BOUND]`).

At the point where `t` is declared, `i` has indeterminate value (not unlikely to be 0).

With indeterminate array size, the accesses `t[i]` produce yet more indeterminate values (and again are undefined behaviour if `i >= sizeof t / sizeof t[0]`).

The printing part,

```
        if(sum == t[i])
        printf("%d is a perfect number. \n", t[i]);
        else
        product = product * t[i];
```

should be moved after the loop used to determine the divisor sum. With that inside the loop, you multiply `product` with `t[i]` a total of `t[i] - 1` times (or `t[i] - 2` if one of the intermediate sums equals `t[i]`) if `t[i]` is not perfect, and `t[i]/2-1` times if `t[i]` is perfect. Also, you print `t[i]/2` times for perfect numbers, and once for abundant numbers if one of the intermediate sums equals `t[i]` (I'm ignoring the theoretical possibility of odd perfect numbers, if there are any, they are far too large for `int`).

Doing that produces correct output here.

Comment: So my mistake was my loop integration. Thank you, you were right!

Answer (score 2):

"Weird product" (for example negative) is caused by [integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow). Your product is `int`, make it bigger, `long long` for example.

You should use `for` loops with `i`, not `while`. Code checking if a number is perfect should be placed in the separate function `bool isPerfect(int number)`.

You meant `sum = 0`, not `somme = 0`. Declaration `t[i]` is also wrong.

Corrected version (compile with `gcc -std=c99 file.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define MAX 10

int t[MAX];

bool isPerfect(int number)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int d = 1; d < number; ++d) // optimization: you can iterate until sqrt(number)
    {
        if (number % d == 0)
        {
            sum += d;
        }
    }
    return sum == number;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Enter your natural numbers. \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i)
    {
        printf("Number %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &t[i]);
    }
    long long product = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i)
    {
        if (isPerfect(t[i]))
        {
            printf("%d is a perfect number. \n", t[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            product = product * t[i];
        }
    }
    printf("The product of the non-perfect numbers is %lld \n", product);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: aren't **for** and **while** loops equivalent if I reinitialize **i** and add a counter (e.g. **i++**).?

Comment: long hasn't fix the problem... I guess the core of the problem are my operations (they seem alright) and my loop (way more likely).

Comment: `For`, `while`, `do-while` are logically equal (when implemented right), however when you are iterating from concrete value to concrete value, the common way to do it is with `for`. It's just one line, not 3.